# Running docker-compose against docker-in-docker (dind)

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

In gitlab-ci, I am trying to run docker-compose within a Docker container. I am using Docker-in-Docker for this.  To test that everything is working, I just execute a `docker info` command. However, when I use the docker-compose image as my image, I get the following error when executing `docker info`:

```
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://docker:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

If I use docker itself as the image, the `docker info` command succeeds. I'm confused by this since the docker-compose image is based on the docker image.

The following .gitlab-ci.yml results in an error from the docker info command:

```
image: docker/compose:debian-1.26.0

stages:
  - test

variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

services:
 - docker:19.03.8-dind

test-provider:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker info
```

If I change the image to `docker:19.03.8`, the docker info command runs fine.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start dockerd in script section explicity. Also you can add script to wait when docker daemon starting succeed. Something like:

```
sudo dockerd & timeout -t 9 bash -c "while [ ! -S /var/run/docker.sock ]; do sleep 3 && ls -lah /var/run/; done" || exit 1
```